# Adding interop 12 to visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop

I can reference either **interop.outlook 14 or 15** in my code. I downloaded **interop.outlook 12.0** and also  installed it but I'm not able to select to reference it as a option. **I am trying to build a dll to pull contacts from outlook**. So instead of writting a dll for each version of office, I want to try write one for office 2007 aka interop 12.0 which probably should cover most scenarios that i would encounter for my app/dll.

My Question is why **I can't add a reference of interop.outlook 12.0**.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I thought i could add a reference to interop 12.0 in my dll exclusively and see if it works with office 2010,office 2013 and maybe office 2003?

Comment: You couldn't add the Interop 12.0 as a reference  to your project ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the property of the added outlook Interop reference and set the `Embed Interop Type` to `False`

Comment: Ok i have a version which references interop.outlook 14.0. I set this attribute to false, what then ? 12.0 is still not there to select? I tried a rebulid, no difference? Or do i do something else?

Comment: @user2289751 You want to add multiple interop version to your project ?

Comment: I would like two options. First to be able to just add interop 12.0. The second option is yes: add multiple interops, say interop 12.0 and interop 14.0?

Comment: Dont user multiple interops instead there are really good open sources which can handle multiple office versions, Check http://netoffice.codeplex.com/